# Uso de IN y OUT en Procedimientos Almacenados

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Un procedimiento almacenado como tal es una rutina que contiene sentencia(s) sql a las cuales se tiene acceso del modo siguiente

```
CALL nombrePA();
```

Un ejemplo sencillo que tenemos sobre un PA es como el siguiente

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE fetchAll()
        SELECT * FROM users;
//
```

Invoco o llamo al PA por medio de `CALL`

```
CALL fetchAll();
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Se crea un delimitador con la doble diagonal `//` por que el símbolo de punto y coma lo contiene la sentencia SQL dentro del PA

Sin embargo sabemos que no todas las sentencias SQL, son estáticas(es decir que no requieran de valores dinámicos)

Es aquí donde entran en uso los valores de tipo:

1. `IN`: Son los valores que espera recibir el PA para otorgarlos a la query que tiene por dentro, procesarla y devolver un resultado
2. `OUT`: Este valor existe en el PA pero puede ser modificado dentro de este mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder utilizar valores dinámicos dentro de un `PA` debemos tener presente es necesario también indicar el tipo de dato a procesar;

**EJEMPLO 1 CON IN**

El siguiente código funcionará por que el PA espera un valor de entrada de tipo `VARCHAR` y al momento de invocarlo pasamos un valor en formato de cadena de texto acorde a

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fetchAll(IN email VARCHAR(40));
CALL fetchAll("mail@mail.com");
```

**EJEMPLO 2 CON IN**

Para este ejemplo vamos a consultar todos los posts asociados a un usuario por un id especifico, donde como podemos notar en el `WHERE` pasamos un valor dinámico en forma de variable que se llama `ìdDinamico`:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE fetchAll1(IN idDinamico INT)
        SELECT nameUser, namePost
        FROM users
        JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
        WHERE users.id  = idDinamico;
//

CALL fetchAll1(1);
```

**EJEMPLO 3 CON OUT**

En el siguiente escenario, vamos a utilizar un valor `OUT` para poder asignar el total de posts asignados a un usuarios en una variable llamada `totalPosts` haciendo uso de `INTO`

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE fetchAll2(IN nameDinamico VARCHAR(40), OUT totalPosts INT)
        SELECT nameUser, COUNT(namePost) INTO nameDinamico, totalPosts
        FROM users
        JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
        WHERE users.nameUser  = nameDinamico;
//

CALL fetchAll2("gatito", @totalPosts);
SELECT @totalPosts;
```

Comment: En el "EJEMPLO 3 CON OUT", ¿por qué almacena `nameDinamico` en el `INTO`?.

Comment: Sería bueno destacar que usar IN / OUT penaliza mucho el rendimiento del motor de la base de datos, no importa que tengas indices, simplemente una lista grande de valores es perjudicial, no hay problema si usas como mucho 100 elementos.